# Omnichannel Supervisor Dashboard: Change queue feature

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, queue, omnichannel

As per the documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=omnichannel_supervisor_change_queues_skills.htm&type=5), Omnichannel Supervisor can change the Agent's queue using the "Change Queues" button. But I don't see that option in the Service console (Classic). Is this feature available only for Lightning?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, the feature is only available in Lightning.

[image: Omni-Channel Supervisor Change Agent Queues]

The use the feature, a Supervisor also needs to have the following permissions:

- Customize Application
- Manage Public List Views and Manage Users

To change skills:

- Create, Read, Update on service resources
- Read Access and Edit Access for the Active field on Service Resource Field-Level Security
- Read Access and Edit Access for the following fields on Service Resource Skill Field-Level Security: End Date, Start Date, and Skill Level

Comment: is there any way to allow someone to be able to change queues for their own account only?

Comment: @AntonioDePalma Not without creating a custom Lightning Component or something along those lines that used a controller that ran in system context. Otherwise, the user wouldn't have the correct permissions. More importantly, if a user can change the queues they're receiving work from, a queue could easily be left without anyone covering it.